# Save filled form to database - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, form-submit

I'm trying to submit a form to an existing database in ruby on rails. I have done some research but none of that works. Here's my form: https://pastebin.com/JfXr054y

Here's my controller:

```
  def landslide_params
      params.require(:landslide).permit(:total_id, :year_id, :start_date, :end_date, :day_number, :continent, :country, :location, :type, :admin_level, :new_lat, :new_long, :mapped, :spatial_area, :fatalities, :injuries, :notes, :sources)
  end
```

How can I link the form to the controller. And also, the form has less fields than the table columns, is that a potential problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of what's happening in the code you're using is cloudy, so I'll review the terminology you're using and the extent of the concepts represented first:

- A **form** is a concept that is represented in HTML as `<form>` the element and a series of input elements, and represented in object-oriented programming in various ways as Form Objects. Rails, notably, doesn't have an opinion or recommendation on how or what to use Form Objects for.
- A **database** is a piece of software that handles the storage and retrieval of data using an interface; most relational databases use SQL as the interface.
- When you *submit* a *form*, you instruct your browser to create an HTTP *request* to the *action* value on the `<form>` tag that includes the *values* present in the form *inputs*.
- When a browser sends a request to your Rails application, the application uses your routes to determine how to handle that *request*.
- The conventional way to handle a *request* in Rails is to route it to a controller *action*.
- In Rails, an *action* is created by defining a *method* on the controller.

Regarding your question, there's no “link” between the form and the controller or an action in the controller, but when a form is submitted, the request triggers a controller action that can handle the request.

You simple access the parameters, ideally using StrongParams (as you've shown), and probably create an instance of an ActiveRecord model to validate and persist the input to your database. The [ActiveRecord Basics Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) provided by Rails is a great place to learn more about the de facto approach to this.

**Yes**, it's okay to have a form that submits values that are not representative of a row in a database column. It's up to your code to handle how that looks. You can have a form that represents multiple rows across multiple tables in your database, or one that represents just a single column out of a dozen.

Comment: Can we start a discussion in chat?

Answer (score 3):

Alrighty, having strong params is great! There are a couple things you have to do to figure out to get this to work. Firstly, yes, you can only submit information into your database for an EXISTING column. If all those attributes you are allowing through your strong params (landslide_params) are in the database, you should be fine. If not, create a couple migrations to add them:

`rails g migration AddAttributesToLandSlide location:string fatalities:integer`

etc.

Secondly, you have to figure out what method in the controller you will be posting to when you hit 'submit' on your form. I assume it will be the create method in the landslide_controller, or something along those lines.

Usually, you would have a 'new' method in the controller that passes in an empty Landslide.new object, and then renders the form/new landslide page. Upon filling out the form and hitting submit, Rails would take you to the create method where you can save the landslide with all the attributes.

Keep in mind, you have to have

`resources :landslides, only: [:new, :create]`

In your routes file for this to work.

Comment: Do you mean I need to put the `render 'form'` in a "new" method?

Comment: No. Rails is smart enough to know that the new method in the landslide controller will render the new.html.erb, which is where you would put the form.

Comment: @dpalazzari There is no magic, and the code is not self-aware. Rails will look for a template following the file locations and naming conventions used by the [resolution algorithms of the autoloader and constant resolver](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `form_tag controller: 'your_controller', action: 'your_controller_action'`.

Have a look at `form_for` documentation. I use it to for both `create` and `update`and it links it to the controller automatically based on whether I'm in `new` or `edit` view:

`<%= form_for(@newsletter) do |f| %>`